# Create categorized renderer from styles won't color categories

Tags: qgis, style, classification

I'm trying to use the tool named 'Create categorized renderer from styles'

[image]

When I classify my layer by an attribute table value in layer properties/symbology/categorized I get different colors automatically.

When I use this tool, it classifies my layer correctly but won't assign different colors to them.

Here is the log output when I'm running the tool.

> Prepare algorithm: native:categorizeusingstyle_1 Running Create
>   categorized renderer from styles [1/12] Input Parameters: {
>   CASE_SENSITIVE: False, FIELD: 'Product', INPUT:
>   '/Users/user/Downloads/python/sample.shp', STYLE: '', TOLERANT: False
>   } No categories could be matched to symbols in file.
>
> 4 categories could not be matched:
>
> Product1 
>   Product2 
>   Product3 
>   Product4
>
> 115 symbols in style were not matched: ∙ “cat trail” ∙ “dash  black” ∙
>   “dash blue” ∙ “dash gray 1” ∙ “dash gray 2” ∙ “dash gray 3” ∙ “dash
>   gray 4” ∙ “dash green” ∙ “dash red” ∙ “diamond blue” ∙ “diamond green”
>   ∙ “diamond red” ∙ “dot  black” ∙ “dot  white” ∙ “dot blue” ∙ “dot
>   brown” ∙ “dot green” ∙ “dot orange” ∙ “dot pink” ∙ “dot purple” ∙ “dot
>   red” ∙ “dot yellow” ∙ “effect drop shadow” ∙ “effect emboss” ∙ “effect
>   neon” ∙ “gradient   plasma” ∙ “gradient  gray fill” ∙ “gradient blue
>   fill” ∙ “gradient brown fill” ∙ “gradient green fill” ∙ “gradient
>   orange fill” ∙ “gradient pink fill” ∙ “gradient purple fill” ∙
>   “gradient red fill” ∙ “gradient yellow fill” ∙ “gray 1 dot” ∙ “gray 1
>   fill” ∙ “gray 1 line” ∙ “gray 2 dot” ∙ “gray 2 fill” ∙ “gray 2 line” ∙
>   “gray 3 dot” ∙ “gray 3 fill” ∙ “gray 3 line” ∙ “gray 4 dot” ∙ “gray 4
>   fill” ∙ “gray 4 line” ∙ “hashed black /” ∙ “hashed black X” ∙ “hashed
>   black \” ∙ “hashed black |” ∙ “hashed black —” ∙ “hashed cblue /” ∙
>   “hashed cblue \” ∙ “hashed cgreen /” ∙ “hashed cgreen \” ∙ “hashed
>   cred /” ∙ “hashed cred \” ∙ “hashed gray /” ∙ “hashed gray \” ∙
>   “honeycomb faux 3d” ∙ “outline black” ∙ “outline blue” ∙ “outline
>   green” ∙ “outline red” ∙ “outline xpattern” ∙ “pattern circles” ∙
>   “pattern dot  blue” ∙ “pattern dot  green” ∙ “pattern dot  red” ∙
>   “pattern dot black” ∙ “pattern zelda” ∙ “pointing arrow” ∙ “shield
>   disability” ∙ “simple  black” ∙ “simple  black line” ∙ “simple  white”
>   ∙ “simple blue fill” ∙ “simple blue line” ∙ “simple brown fill” ∙
>   “simple brown line” ∙ “simple green fill” ∙ “simple green line” ∙
>   “simple orange fill” ∙ “simple orange line” ∙ “simple pink fill” ∙
>   “simple pink line” ∙ “simple purple fill” ∙ “simple purple line” ∙
>   “simple red fill” ∙ “simple red line” ∙ “simple yellow fill” ∙ “simple
>   yellow line” ∙ “topo airport” ∙ “topo building” ∙ “topo camp” ∙ “topo
>   foot” ∙ “topo forest” ∙ “topo hospital” ∙ “topo hydrology” ∙ “topo
>   main road” ∙ “topo path” ∙ “topo pop capital” ∙ “topo pop city” ∙
>   “topo pop house” ∙ “topo pop village” ∙ “topo railway” ∙ “topo road” ∙
>   “topo steps” ∙ “topo swamp” ∙ “topo urban” ∙ “topo water” ∙ “triangle
>   blue” ∙ “triangle green” ∙ “triangle red” OK. Execution took 4.46 s (1
>   outputs).

Is it possible to have this tool assign random (any) colors to classified items?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't think you're using the right algorithm at all..

Comment: I am trying to categorize a layer using attribute column values. I can do this with symbology of layer properties manually I can select categorized symbology, select a column to classify by then click on classify and it gives me the result in various colors but when I try to embed this process to a model I can't find anything that works like symbology tab in the layer properties. It classifies my layer using the column perfectly fine but it doesn't assign random colors.